# How do I interface a mySQL database using BlueJ on a raspberry pi?

Tags: java, mysql, raspberry-pi

I have a fully setup MySQL database running on my pi and I am trying to get it to be able to be called upon in a BlueJ program. I have downloaded the Connector/j driver and set up the code in java. However, I have been banging my head against instructional youtube videos and articles trying to get it to work and nothing has seemed to make a change. Another thing I see that may be notable is that when the code compiles it has no errors, adding to my confusion. Also, the whole thing about where to place the driver is very confusing to me, as is right now I have it stored in the BlueJ project file. Here is the code :

```
import java.sql 

public class mySQL { 

public static void main (String[]args) { 

try{ 

class.forName( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ) ;
Connection conn  = 

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/gui
tarDBuser=root&password=toor" ) ;
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ; 


ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from A") ; 
while(rs.next() ){ 
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1) ); 
    rs.close() ; 
    stmt.close() ; 
    conn.close() ;
} 

}catch(SQLException se) { 
System.out.println("SQL Exception:") ; 

  while( se != null) { 
  System.out.println("state: " + se.getSQLState() ) ; 
  System.out.println("Message: " + se.getMessage()  ); 
  System.out.println("Error: " + se.getErrorCode() ); 

  se = se.getNextException() ; 
 } 

  }catch(Exception e) 
{ 
System.out.println(e) ; 
} 
} 
}
```

When compiled it gives me an instance that says "No fields" and gives me a button to "Show Static Fields" but when I click on the it gives the "No Fields" thing again. Im mega confused and any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you running your code on the Pi? Or just the database?

Comment: @mkasberg BlueJ and the database are both running on the pi

Comment: `When compiled it gives me an instance that says "No fields"` What says no fields? And where are the buttons? Are you able to connect to the database using the mysql command line interface?